# Compare two files with the third column in each file matching but the second fith columns do not match using awk

Tags: awk, sed, grep

### Say file1 is:

```
a b c d f
aa bb cc dd ef
ab bc dg ef ge
ao ob dy ed co
```

### and file2 is:

```
a b c d e 
aa bb cc dd ee
ab bc de ef ge
ao ob dy ed co
```

### the expected output should be:

```
a b c d f 
aa bb cc dd ef
```

Here is what I tried:

```
 awk 'NR==FNR{c[$3,$5]++;next};($3 in c[$3]) && !($5 in c[$5]) > 0' file1 file2
```

Comment: oops you're right let me edit it!

Comment: if you put `$3,$5` as a key into `c[]`, searching for a single value, i.e `$3` (or `$5`) will never match. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this?

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$3]=$0;next} 
       $3 in a{split(a[$3],r); if($5!=r[5])print}' file2 file1

a b c d f
aa bb cc dd ef
```

checking 5th field for not matching.

I guess, this can be simplified to,

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$3]=$5;next} $3 in a && a[$3]!=$5' file2 file1
```

Comment: Ahh I see, i was wrongly using the array. Thanks your solution is great!